# Cryptsetup password not working on new install, and weird proliferation of characters

Tags: disk-encryption, ubuntu-16.04

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad X61, and ticked the box to encrypted the full system.

When it finished installing and rebooted, it did not accept the password. It fails with `"Bad password or options?"`.

I have ruled out caps lock and keyboard layout I think, but of course it could be user error.

However, something else is happening which makes me think something is wrong. While the GUI for entering the password is on screen, you can press the down arrow key to switch to a terminal, which also has a password prompt, and they you can arrow up to get back to the GUI. But each time you do this it adds 2 asterisks as though two more characters have been typed in. If you type one character in the GUI and then switch to terminal, back to GUI, and then back and forth again you would have 9 asterisks in the box as though you had typed 9 characters.

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and just opting for home folder encryption, and this worked fine. but I would like to know what is wrong with the full disk encryption, if this is a bug or something I don't understand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this process with Kubuntu but yes I've ran into the same issue. Currently have a question awaiting answer at askubuntu.

I've figured out something, with a 'more secure' password. over 12 characters, random plus special characters for some reason fails to work to decrypt after 100's of times entering it. When I re-did install and used 'test' w/out quotes as the password, that works fine. Weird.

Maybe, logging in when password is test and manually changing the password to your 'more secure' one would work. Cryptsetup is not developed by the same people as Kubuntu, so the configuration of it should works without issues. My concern is why this built in way of encrypting isn't working. If they know it's bugged, and can't fix it then remove it. If they can fix it, then fix it. If their are password requirements overexceeded or underexceeded then list the requirements next to password box and most importantly, do not let user proceed with an 'invalid choice of a password'. If these were met, it would make process easier on us users. But hope to figure this out soon enough.